# What is the correct proxy for apt-get?

Tags: apt, windows, proxy

apt-get can't locate any packages, most probably as I am behind a corporate firewall and need to configure a proxy.
My windows machine is functioning correctly. Is it possible to determine the correct proxy from it ?

Comment: What command are you running and what is the exact error? (update your question for answering it) What I can guess from your question is that you are running upgrade without running update command. If so, run `sudo apt-get update` first in order to get the latest list of packages.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an easy question to answer.
If proxy setting cannot be read from Internet Explorer, then probably WBA is used to autoconfigure browser proxy. Just download wpad.dat file by yourself and extract proxy settings from it. Basically try to download wpad.dat from following urls:

- wpad.department.branch.example.com/wpad.dat
- wpad.branch.example.com/wpad.dat
- wpad.example.com/wpad.dat
- wpad.com/wpad.dat (in incorrect implementations, see note in Security below)
- or just wpad.dat

Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Proxy_Autodiscovery_Protocol for more instructions.

If you company is using proxy like ISA Server with NTLM authentication, you'll need something like [cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/).

There are many tutorials on the web, eg. [this one](http://www.howtoforge.com/linux-ntlm-authentication-proxy-isa-server-with-cntlm).

However if your company is using regular proxy server, then just configure your network adapter with company proxy server settings.

For shell programs like apt-get set proxy, before you invoke apt-get command do:

```
$ export HTTP_PROXY=http://server.ip:port
$ export HTTPS_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY
$ export FTP_PROXY=$HTTP_PROXY
```